# Cart page prices calculating issue with comma not showing total prices $ NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calculating prices on cart page here [http://199.192.21.232/~admin/cart.php](http://199.192.21.232/%7Eadmin/cart.php) please add two products on cart and check. it is working fine if price is under 999 and if price like 1,000 then the total prices not showing $ NaN below is my code.

```
<script>
function increment_quantity(product_id, price) {
    var inputQuantityElement = $("#quantity-"+product_id);
    var newQuantity = parseInt($(inputQuantityElement).val())+1;
    var newPrice = newQuantity * price;
    save_to_db(product_id, newQuantity, newPrice);
}
function decrement_quantity(product_id, price) {
    var inputQuantityElement = $("#quantity-"+product_id);
    if($(inputQuantityElement).val() > 1) 
    {
    var newQuantity = parseInt($(inputQuantityElement).val()) - 1;
    var newPrice = newQuantity * price;
    save_to_db(product_id, newQuantity, newPrice);
    }
}
function numberWithCommas(number) {
    var parts = number.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
function save_to_db(product_id, new_quantity, newPrice) {
    var inputQuantityElement = $("#quantity-"+product_id);
    var priceElement = $("#cart-price-"+product_id);
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('action', 'cart-qty');
    form_data.append('product_id', product_id);
    form_data.append('new_quantity', new_quantity);
    form_data.append('new_price', newPrice);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'load.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success : function(response) {
            $(inputQuantityElement).val(new_quantity);
            $(priceElement).attr('data-price', newPrice);
            $(priceElement).text("$ "+numberWithCommas(Number(newPrice.toFixed(2))));
            var totalQuantity = 0;
            $("input[id*='quantity-']").each(function() {
                var cart_quantity = $(this).val();
                totalQuantity = parseInt(totalQuantity) + parseInt(cart_quantity);
            });
            $("#ttl-qty").text(totalQuantity);
            var totalItemPrice = 0;
            $("p[id*='cart-price-']").each(function() {
                var cart_price = $(this).attr('data-price').replace("$","");
                totalItemPrice = Number(totalItemPrice) + Number(cart_price);
            });
            $("#sttlprc").text("$ "+numberWithCommas(totalItemPrice.toFixed(2)));
            $("#ttlprc").text("$ "+numberWithCommas(totalItemPrice.toFixed(2)));
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Code Updated

Comment: Can you please post your code on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: i added it here https://codepen.io/amiralamkhan/pen/jOrOboq sorry i using codepen for first time i just added but i see the script is not working.

Comment: Thanks Sawan i just fixed the issue my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it i just take the value of the price in data attribute without $ and format and it is working fine now. thanks for your help sawan.

Comment: Also, use can use

$("p[id*='cart-price-']").each(function () {
    var cart_price = $(this).text().replace("$ ", "").replace(",", ""); //add replace(",", "")
    totalItemPrice = Number(totalItemPrice) + Number(cart_price);
  });